# Click event in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add players into an array of objects and then display their name in a div. This is my situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzt0w3yx/14/

Searching through questions on stackoverflow one of the solutions were to use a closure like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
    (function(index) {
....click event...
    })(i);
}
```

But when I press submit, everytime I see the same name as output, plus a weird gap under it.

Comment: Why do you register 5 times the click listener ? (it's been called 5 times when you click on the button)

Comment: What's the point of the closure and the for loop?

Comment: There is no need to use iteration. Take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67etja05/)

Comment: @Beckham, please see my updated answer, it targets both of your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the **[fixed fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hzt0w3yx/20/)**. However I would be better able to help you if I could understand why you had the loop there?

```
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
        name = $("input[name='name']").val();
        money = $("input[name='money']").val();

        players.push(new Player(name, money, 0, 0, 0));
        $("input[name='name']").val("");
        $("input[name='money']").val("");

        $("#log").append(players[index++].name + "<br>");

        if(index == numOfPlayers) {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
  });
```

**Why the strange empty space?**

The loop caused that you printed the `<br>` multiple times instead of just once. You regiestered 5 click event handlers instead of just one handler and all 5 handlers were called each time the button was clicked.

Instead of the loop, it is sufficient to register the click event just once and when the index reaches the desired amount of players, the submit button is disabled so the user will not be able to add more than 5 players:

```
if(index == numOfPlayers) {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

**Why always first player was printed?**

You were not increasing the `index` variable which is why you always printed the same - first player. Now the index is increased on every click (please, notice the `index++`):

```
$("#log").append(players[index++].name + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly are you looping? Right now you are adding the click handler 5 times, that explains why there is some empty space. Your function gets executed each time, if you look at your players array you'll see it will get 5 new players with empty names every time you click.

You want to add them when the click happens, something like this should work:

```
  function Player(name, money, bet, tmp, diceSum) {
      this.name = name;
      this.money = money;
      this.bet = bet;
      this.tmp = tmp;
      this.diceSum = diceSum;
  }

  var players = [];
  var name, money;
  var numOfPlayers = 5;

  $("#submit").click(
    function() {
      name = $("input[name='name']").val();
      money = $("input[name='money']").val();

      var newPlayer = new Player(name, money, 0, 0, 0);          
      players.push(newPlayer);

      $("#log").append(newPlayer.name + "<br>");

      $("input[name='name']").val("");
      $("input[name='money']").val("");

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/hzt0w3yx/17/

Just use length property of your goal array. This code will print the name of last player (no loop is needed):

```
$("#log").append(players[players.length - 1].name + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand the reason you try to use loop here.
You should loop in the print log, not looping when you add new Player to players array.
Additionally, you should add `index++;` at the end of your loop too

```
function Player(name, money, bet, tmp, diceSum) {
    this.name = name;
    this.money = money;
    this.bet = bet;
    this.tmp = tmp;
    this.diceSum = diceSum;
  }
var players = [];
var name, money;
var numOfPlayers = 5;
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
       name = $("input[name='name']").val();
       money = $("input[name='money']").val();
       players.push(new Player(name, money, 0, 0, 0));
       $("input[name='name']").val("");
       $("input[name='money']").val("");
       for( var i = 0; i< numOfPlayers; i++) {
         (function(index){
            $("#log").append(players[index].name + "<br>");
            index++;
         })(i);
       }
     }
);
```